# is there possibility to add extension to firefox in developer mode?

Tags: firefox-addon

I mean without compressing it to *.xpi. Other browsers like chrome or opera understand when I drag a folder with extension files from system explorer to therirs addon-manager tab, but firefox, when I unpack *.xpi and try to install it as a folder shows : "This addon could not be installed because it appears corrupt" message.

Reason for this that when I try to change the code I must every time to pack my source files to xpi and then refresh the extension. Other way, like in chrome, the browser automatically updates extension when files were changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an *extension proxy file*. The file is placed in your extensions directory in your profile. It should be named as the `id` field of your addon. Inside this file you put a single line with the actual path of the source.

Before copying the proxy file you should uninstall the corresponding xpi addon you may have installed.

Check [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Setting_up_extension_development_environment) for more resources on setting up your dev environment.